# MariaDB data in MySQL Workbench - blob fields

Tags: mysql, blob, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have created federated tables to query off a remote MariaDB table in my local instance of MySQL. I'm having issues with blob fields. In MySQL it doesn't seem to understand the column_exists and column_get functions. It keeps giving me a "Error Code 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...etc".

Query that works in MariaDB:

```
select id,demographics, column_exists(custom_data, 'c_field1'),
       column_get(custom_data, 'c_field1' as integer) from tbl_custom_data
where column_exists(custom_data, 'c_field1') = 1
```

Can anyone provide any insights? Thanks!

Comment: You can try with another client like HeidiSQL.

Comment: Would you say looking up blob values in MySQL Workbench is not possible then?

Comment: Mysql workbench as built in capabilities to work with mysql databases...with that in mind and, sice they may look like the same, they are different engines, so, it makes sense that it doesn't recognize mariadb specific functions, like `column_exists` and `column_get`

Comment: See if phpmyadmin is more forgiving about the differences between MySQL and MariaDB.